# Filter item from JSON using key:value pair

Tags: php, json

I have JSON array

```
[
{"id":"476","jobid":"324","remarks":"Job 500","status":"Open"},
{"id":"477","jobid":"324","remarks":"Job 501","status":"Closed"},
{"id":"481","jobid":"324","remarks":"Job 502","status":"Cancelled"}
]
```

How can I get `remarks` for the status `Closed` using PHP ?

Better if possible without loop

Comment: You should know you need to show some efforts

Comment: I've written a project that allows you to query JSON and arrays in PHP: https://github.com/benmajor/JQL

Comment: @Andreas If I know, I wouldn't have asked here. And if I was stucked at some point, I will surely be more specific at what I have done so far, and where I got stuck. In this case, I have googled (I am not sure if I was using correct keywords for searching), but I couldn't find how to do.

Comment: It's not about knowing, it's about showing an effort in solving it yourself.

Comment: You can show what methods you have tried. You show that you have looked at other similar questions and explain how that does not solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

Check out [JQL](https://github.com/benmajor/JQL):

```
$jql = new JQL('[
  {"id":"476","jobid":"324","remarks":"Job 500","status":"Open"},
  {"id":"477","jobid":"324","remarks":"Job 501","status":"Closed"},
  {"id":"481","jobid":"324","remarks":"Job 502","status":"Cancelled"}
]');

$result = $jql->select('remarks')->where('status = Closed')->fetch();
```

Answer (score 1):

Without loops, that depends.
It's impossible to do without any loops, but the loops can be done in the background and not in php.

This will get the column for status and filter out anything that is not closed.
Then set the key for 'remarks'.

```
var_dump(array_intersect(array_column($arr, 'status', 'remarks'), ["Closed"]));
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  ["Job 501"]=>
  string(6) "Closed"
}
```

https://3v4l.org/mNUr6